# Camunda : How to configure external Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, camunda

I use spring boot starter to run camunda. I can run with h2 database. But when i try to connect to postgres i havethe following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at fr.casden.eficas.workflow.Application.main(Application.java:10)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Here are my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <groupId>fr.my.work</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-workflow</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Driver JDBC Postgresql-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.200</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

application properties :

```
camunda.bpm.admin-user.id=demo
camunda.bpm.admin-user.password=demo
camunda.bpm.database.type=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/workflow
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=workflow
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Spring Boot Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
  }

}
```

What am i missing please ?

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using? spring.datasource.url changed to spring.datasource.jdbc-url in Spring Boot 2.x

Comment: I am using the spring boot 2

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the version of postgres in your pom.xml and instead give `<scope>runtime</scope>`

Try to give this in application.yaml:

```
  # Database
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  # JPA properties
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    open-in-view: false
    generate-ddl: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Springboot version - 2.1.2.RELEASE works fine with camunda bpm version -7.13.0

**Here is the pom.xml entry -**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
  </properties>
  <groupId>com.xxxx.workflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxxx-camunda-bpm</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>7.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
      <version>7.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>7.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and application.yml

```
camunda:
  admin-user:
    id: demo
    password: demo
  bpm:
    database:
      type: postgres
    table-prefix: camunda.
    schema-update: true

spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
 datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    #DB connection:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/workflow?stringtype=unspecified
    username: xxxxx
    password: xxxxx
```